# Outlook 2010 AddIn: Add a new control next to Search textbox

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am planning to develop an AddIn for MS Outlook 2010. This addin will place a control next to Search Textbox in outlook. But I don't know how to achieve this. I searched a lot but found addins for Ribbon/Pane. Any pointer would really helpful for me.

```
My Environment: VS2012 Ultimate, MS Outlook 2010, C#
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicitly customize that area.  A VSTO Task Pane or Add-in Express Form Region could give you some alternatives.  Otherwise, you'd need to use the Win32 API and do some window subclassing to paint a control there, as per the technique used here:

Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook in C++ for Visual Studio 2008
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/